# Angular remove item from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have a list in which when i click over an item i generate an input text and i add the attributes of that input in a json. Actually if i click over an item of the list for more times it adds at json all of that times i click. For example, if i click 3 times the first item of the list i have this json:

```
{
    "newArray":
    [
        {
            "attrname": "asd1",
            "attrValue": "",
            "attrType": "text"
        },
        {
            "attrname": "asd1",
            "attrValue": "",
            "attrType": "text"
        },
        {
            "attrname": "asd1",
            "attrValue": "",
            "attrType": "text"
        }
    ]
}
```

What i would instead is that if i click 1 time i add the item, then if i click again it removes the item from json. This is the code by the way:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='mycontroller'>

    <div data-ng-repeat="item in myNewArray.newArray track by $index">
        <div ng-if="item.attrType == 'text'">
            <input id="form-f{{$index}}" type="text" placeholder="{{item.attrname}}" data-ng-model="item.attrValue"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="object in getItems.data">
        <div data-ng-repeat="att in object.objects">
            <ul ng-repeat="data in att.attributes">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="pushItems(data)" style="cursor:pointer">{{data.attrname}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    {{myNewArray}}
</div>
```

the angular part:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "$http",
    function($scope, $http){
        $scope.getItems = {
    "data": [
        {
            "label": "first",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd1",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd2",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "key": "bolla"
        },
        {
            "label": "second",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "secondObj",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd3",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "key": "2"
        }
    ]

};
    $scope.filterSelected = $scope.getItems.data[0].objects;

        $scope.myNewArray = {
            newArray: [

            ]
        }
        $scope.pushItems = function pushItems(items) {
            $scope.myNewArray.newArray.push(angular.copy(items));
            console.log($scope.myNewArray);
        }

}]);
```

And here the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/42/

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to delete last item, first item or all array

Comment: Is it really necessary to push the copy `angular.copy(items)` or you can also push original?

Comment: mmm angular.copy(items) it's better right now. Btw you have to think the list like a checkbox. If i click in an item i add that item to array, if i click again the same item i remove it from array

Comment: so, summary, i can add the same item of the list in the array only ones at time while actually you can add the same item for infinite times. Understand now?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the copy. It's just simpler with original, and in most cases preferred.

Comment: @dfsq ok, you can use the original if you want, but that is not my problem right now.. The problem is the one i ask. If you prefer btw you can use the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure wether you really want to push a copy of the items in the array, in cases like yours it makes more sense to compose an array of real items so that you can manipulate array items and it would be reflected on originals too. In this case adding/removing would look like this:

```
$scope.pushItems = function pushItems(items) {
    var index = $scope.myNewArray.newArray.indexOf(items);
    if (index !== -1) {
        $scope.myNewArray.newArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else {
        $scope.myNewArray.newArray.push(items);
    }
};
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/f5nxsqxm/

Comment: Ok that is perfect!!! the copy, you're right, now doesn't need. Your code is what i need. Thanks

Comment: Yes, with copy `indexOf` would not work. In case you want to see implementation with copies it will be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/f5nxsqxm/1/

Comment: i've got the same problem changing a bit the code :( here the question if you want help me. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374113/angular-remove-item-from-json-click-over-again

Answer (score 2):

I would swap your attributes JSON array to an object literal and use the attribute names as keys. This would ensure you have at most one item per attribute name.  Object literal would work more like a dictionary which appears to be closer to what you're looking to use.

Should be more performant traversing an object literal than an array here as well.