# remove item from json click over again

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I've asked some times ago how to remove an item from json more exactly here: [Angular remove item from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367472/angular-remove-item-from-json/30367765?noredirect=1#comment48826327_30367765)

and it worked well.. now i've got the same problem but the code is a little bit different. In summary, i have a list. When i click over an item it adds its attributes in a json. I would that if i click again in this item it removes its attributes from json. So, i click Item1 and adds, click again Item1 and removes.

This is what i tried

```
myApp.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "$http",
    function($scope, $http){
        $scope.getItems = {
    "data": [
        {
            "label": "first",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attrname": "Item1",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrname": "Item2",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "key": "bolla"
        }
    ]

};
    $scope.filterSelected = $scope.getItems.data[0].objects;

        $scope.myNewArray = {
            objects: [

            ]
        }

        $scope.createjson = function(attribute, items) {
            var obj = {};
            obj.name = attribute;
            obj.attributes = [];
            obj.attributes.push(items);
            return obj;
        }

        $scope.checkIfAttributeExists = function(attribute) {        
            for(var i=0; i<$scope.myNewArray.objects.length; i++) {                
                if($scope.myNewArray.objects[i]["name"] == attribute) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        $scope.pushItems = function pushItems(attribute, items) {
            var index = $scope.checkIfAttributeExists(attribute);
            if(index == -1) {
                var obj = $scope.createjson(attribute, items);
                $scope.myNewArray.objects.push(obj);
            } else if(index !== -1) {

                $scope.myNewArray.objects.splice(index, 1);

            }else {
                $scope.myNewArray.objects[index].attributes.push(items);
            }
        }

        $scope.showNewJson = function() {
            return $scope.myNewArray;
        }
}]);
```

Seems that the problem is in the index. Here i created a jsFiddle:

Update link:
https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/53/

Actually this is what the code do:

```
{"objects":[{"name":"firstObj","attributes":[{"attrname":"Item1","attrValue":"","attrType":"text"}]},{"name":"firstObj","attributes":[{"attrname":"Item1","attrValue":"","attrType":"text"}]},{"name":"firstObj","attributes":[{"attrname":"Item2","attrValue":"","attrType":"text"}]}]}
```

As you can see there are two times the attribute "Item1" because i clicked twice over it. But if i click twice the Item1 get to disappear! So the correct json will be:

```
{"objects":[{"name":"firstObj","attributes":[{"attrname":"Item2","attrValue":"","attrType":"text"}]}]}
```

Comment: A little suggestion to your code:  your function definition is $scope.checkIfAttributeExists = function(attribute) {     ..., while the actual call is "var index = $scope.checkIfAttributeExists(items);" It is SO confusing!

Comment: i updated the link of fiddle

Comment: Don't pass property values into the function, work with the whole object. Your code is far more complex than needed. Also get an understanding of what `json` is. You are not creating or working with json, you are working with javascript objects and arrays. `json` is simply a *string data transfer format*  that resembles javascript objects and arrays

Comment: That array is what i will send to the server.. But i have to send what i need. So 1 attribute for each item selected. Not more. Understand?

Comment: try to see my little edit of the quest

Comment: Yes...fully understand what you are trying to do. But you can check index of the object exists, without needing to loop through values

Comment: Can you show me please how can i do using the jsfiddle created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code as follows:

HTML

```
 <ul ng-repeat="item in att.attributes">
      <li>
           <a ng-click="pushItems(item)">{{item.attrname}}</a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

JS

```
$scope.pushItems = function pushItems(item) { // note only single argument now
    // index the whole item object
    var itemIndex = $scope.myNewArray.objects.indexOf(item);
    if (itemIndex == -1) {
        // if index doesn't exist ...add to array
        $scope.myNewArray.objects.push(item);
    } else {
        // otherwise remove from array
        $scope.myNewArray.objects.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }
}
```

by working with the object itself you don't need to look at properties of the object to do your check to see if it exists or not, check the index of the actual object instead

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/54/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!It's working! It's perfect! And you helped me to make the code better. Thanks!

Comment: charlieftl i need a help here :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435239/upload-angular-multi-part

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = $scope.checkIfAttributeExists(attribute);
```

You are passing the wrong argument.

Comment: if i pass var index = $scope.checkIfAttributeExists(attribute); it removes the item if i click over again, true..but it removes that item even if i click the second item.

Comment: If you click different items (Item1, Item2, Item3 ...) they add to json. But can be only one of them. So if you click again in the Item1 you will have the list like: (Item2, Item3..) without the first one.

Comment: I want a single attribute of that item i click.

Comment: Any help? Understand now my problem?